# Django- Clear user cache when user logged out

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-signals

I am using `django.core.cache` to store user roles related data in the cache. The user roles are stored as keys `roles_<user.id>` in the cache.

I want to delete the `roles_<user.id>` key from the cache whenever theuser logs out from the system.

I used the **user_logged_out** auth signal for this but somehow this signal is not working(not deleting the cache data).

I have created a receiver in **signals.py** as:

```
def clear_user_cache(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    cache.delete('roles_{}'.format(user.id))


user_logged_out.connect(clear_user_cache)
```

**My logout url is:**

```
url(r'^accounts/logout/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name='auth_logout'),
```

**Logout in template:**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'auth_logout' %}"><i class="la la-sign-out"></i>{% trans 'Logout' %}</a>
```

When I hit the logout button, the user is logged out but the cache is not being cleared. If I try printing some statements in the signal receiver, they are not getting printed.

I though the url in the template might have caused this problem so I tried changing it to:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"><i class="la la-sign-out"></i>{% trans 'Logout' %}</a>
```

But still nothing happened.

How can I make the logout signal to fire when the user is logged out?

I am using Django==1.8.18 and python2.7

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your signals haven't been registered. If the **signals.py** file is in the **user** app then you need to modify **user/apps.py** and **user/__init__.py**

You could also register them by importing in your models but I think this way is a bit cleaner.

```
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class UserConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'user'

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals


# __init__.py

default_app_config = 'user.apps.UserConfig'
```

Comment: Can you explain the configuration `default_app_config = 'user.apps.UserConfig'
` in the users/__init__.py

Comment: My apps configuration is not being able to find the module named `users.apps` as my app name is users. Instead I copied my receiver function and kept it in users/__init__.py file and now it is working.

Comment: The line `user.apps.UserConfig` is basically dot notation for the `<folder>.<file>.<class>` where the class is a subclass of `AppConfig`. I can't be sure without seeing the full error message but it could be that one of the names is incorrect. Try `users.apps.UsersConfig`

Answer (score 0):

As @bdoubleu suggested in his answer that my signals might have not been registered, I tried defining my receiver function inside the **users/__init__.py** file instead of **signals.py**.

This caused the signal to be activated whenever user logs out from the system and the user cache for respective user is cleared.

This approach was easy to implement and indeed solved my query. I am open to any other suggestions that are better than this approach.